# Product Collection Filtered by Multiselect Attribute in magento

Tags: magento

Hi i want to get all the product collection based on a multiselect attribute.
i wrote the following query but it is giving me all the products not getting filtered.

```
  $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('author_name', 45)
 foreach($collection as $product){
        echo $product->getName().'<br />';
    }
```

can any one give me the query how to fetch collection filtered by multiselect attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
      ->addAttributeToFilter('author_name',array('in' => array('45', '46','47')));
```

Answer (score 0):

try `addAttributeToFilter('author_name', array('eq' => 45))`